# Consumir SOAP con PHP + agregar parametros + key

Tags: php, soap

Estoy intentando consumir un servicio soap que consulta el nro de rut de cada ciudadano, esto funciona en un SOAPUI, y lo estoy i
implementando con php para realizarlo a nivel de codigo, como pudiera configurar para pasarle la key? Sabiendo
que la key en el programa SOAPUI la toma desde un archivo. Hasta ahora la respuesta es error interno

```
     <?php 
    
    require ('lib/Soap/nusoap.php');
    
        //url del webservice
        $wsdl="https://efactura.dgi.gub.uy:6470/ePrueba/ws_personaGetActEmpresarialPrueba?wsdl";
        
        //instanciando un nuevo objeto cliente para consumir el webservice
        $client=new nusoap_client($wsdl);
     
        //pasando los parámetros a un array
        $param=array('dgi' => 'WS_PersonaGetActEmpresarial', 'rut'=>'218691450019');
     
        //llamando al método y pasándole el array con los parámetros
        $resultado = $client->call('wsasidepto', $param);
```

[image: something]

Realmente no se como configurar la la clave api sabiendo que desde el programa me SOAPUI me pide es un archivo. También puede ser que me devuelve ese error interno por la api. Les agradecería alguna guia.

Deberia ingresar la key aqui. Estoy esperando la key para poder acceder. El error que me dice la guia [esta es la guia](https://www.efactura.dgi.gub.uy/files/web-services-consulta-de-rut?es)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El error interno que me arroja es por la entrada de parametros. Que no es la correcta. El error que deberia arrojar por la key seria = >Error al consumir el Servicio Web.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: tu ejemplo ni siquiera menciona algo como una llave. Al menos podrías mostrar donde la incluyes en SoapUI.

Comment: hola @ffflabs, actualize la pregunta agregandole mas informacion. Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No quise usar nusoap porque tengo más experiencia con la clase SoapClient común y corriente. Para lo que importa, es casi lo mismo. Los siguientes comentarios son solamente para ayudarte a llegar al error esperado y no a un error inexplicable.

La documentación [que dejaste](https://www.efactura.dgi.gub.uy/files/web-services-consulta-de-rut?es) señala que:

El servicio publicado (**WS_PersonaGetActEmpresarial**) expone el método **Execute** que se detalla a continuación:

| Servicio | Método | Parám.Request |
| --- | --- | --- |
| WS_PersonaGetActEmpresarial | Execute | Rut (String) |

Tú estás creando un arreglo con el que le pasarías al webservice los parámetros `dgi` y `rut`.

```
 //pasando los parámetros a un array
 $param=array('dgi' => 'WS_PersonaGetActEmpresarial', 'rut'=>'218691450019');
```

- `dgi` es un prefijo de namespace, que es una variable sin significado en particular. No es un parámetro.
- El webservice no espera que le indiques que quieres usar el servicio `WS_PersonaGetActEmpresarial` porque al inicializar tu cliente SOAP con el WSDL de `WS_PersonaGetActEmpresarial` eso ya quedó establecido.
- **R**ut debe ir con mayúscula.

Acto seguido, llamas al método `call` diciéndole que delegue a un método `wsasidepto`

```
    //llamando al método y pasándole el array con los parámetros
    $resultado = $client->call('wsasidepto', $param);
```

No tengo idea de dónde habrá salido ese método, pero no aparece en la documentación [ni en el WSDL](https://efactura.dgi.gub.uy:6470/ePrueba/ws_personaGetActEmpresarialPrueba?wsdl). El único método que expone el servicio
`WS_PersonaGetActEmpresarial` es `Execute`.

Por otro lado, se supone que el cliente SOAP debiera  "entender" el WSDL y ofrecerte una manera amigable de llamar a los servicios, de manera que el uso de métodos de bajo nivel como `nusoap_client::call` y [SoapClient::_soapCall](https://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapcall.php) debiran ser sólo el plan B.

Dado que declaro un cliente como

```
   $soapClient = new SoapClient(
        'https://efactura.dgi.gub.uy:6470/ePrueba/ws_personaGetActEmpresarialPrueba?wsdl',
        [
            'trace' => true,
            'exceptions' => true
        ]
    );
```

Puedo consumir `Execute` haciendo

```
$result = $soapClient->Execute(['Rut' => '218691450019']);
```

Este método está recibiendo un solo parámetro, que es `['Rut' => '218691450019']`. O sea ocupo

```
$result = $soapClient->Execute($parametro1);
```

Si yo en cambio utilizase `soapCall` sería

```
$result = $soapClient->_soapCall('Execute', [ $parametro1 ]);
```

Si te fijas, la función tiene dos argumento: el nombre del método como string, y un arreglo con todos los parámetros que le pasarías a un método X del webservice.
Tú lo estabas llamando directo.

Ocupando cualquiera de estos dos, obtengo:

```
SoapFault {#1791 ▼
  #message: "Error al consumir el Servicio Web"
  #code: 0
  #file: "/var/task/user/app/Http/Middleware/PreloadCode.php(123) : eval()'d code"
  #line: 13
  +"faultstring": "Error al consumir el Servicio Web"
  +"faultcode": "soapenv:Client"
  +"detail": {#1795 ▼
    +"GenericFault": {#1797 ▼
      +"Respuestas": {#1798 ▼
        +"Respuesta": {#1794 ▼
          +"Codigo": "0"
          +"Descripcion": "Error al consumir el Servicio Web"
          +"Detalle": "No signature in message!"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

La inspección de lo enviado me dice:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="DGI_Modernizacion_Consolidado">
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns1:WS_PersonaGetActEmpresarial.Execute>
      <ns1:Rut>218691450019</ns1:Rut>
    </ns1:WS_PersonaGetActEmpresarial.Execute>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

que es muy parecido a lo que muestra tu SoapUI. Recuerda que `ns1` o `dgi` son un prefijo irrelevante.

[Te dejé un playground para que inspecciones la respuesta incluyendo la forma del XML.](https://laravelplayground.com/#/snippets/6522fa59-e756-4606-85b8-d0bc24bc56a7)

Comment: Lo termine logrando de manera nativa con php, pero tu ejemplo esta mas completo y mas detallado. Llegamos al mismor resultado. Lo que me esta faltando ahora es autenticarme. Con un certificado digital que ellos rquieren, el cual me dicen que lo solicite en el correo uruguayo. Lo que no se, es que, si ese certificado digital habra manera de vincularlo con el programa en php. No se si es un archivo comun o si ese certificado trae una key. o algo por el estilo

Comment: De lo que dice el PDF sólo se puede ver que el archivo del certificado tiene extensión P12, lo cual sugiere que es un PFX. Si ese es el caso hay dos maneras de usarlo: firmando el XML de cada request o añadiendo un soapHeader. No hay nada mágico acá. Si se puede hacer con soapUI con mayor razón se puede hacer en PHP que está mucho más cerca del request nativo del sistema.

Comment: gracias @ffflabs cuando tenga el certificado te comento que tal me fue.

Comment: Ya tengo genere la clave privada y ellos me la validaron devolviéndome una publica. Tendria que enviar esa clave en cada request o un header. Pero tendria que enviar la clave literalmente como un parametro? ejemplo: header(array(licensekey=> '12onmsdofgmasodfmasiom23o4i2m3o423')). Algo asi? Porque he intentado de muchas maneras y no he tenido exito.